# Searching gaana database for a specific output

Tags: json, api

I was surfing gaana.com music website that has also released its developer version api.gaana.com. The documentation of api is here http://developer.gaana.com/resources/meta-data-api/tracks/

I wish to query the database but i am struggling with the syntax and I am unable to follow the documentation guidelines. try and retry got me a Json result but I dont know how to put conditions.

Example, I want to search the database for all tracks where the artist name is "kishor kumar" and the rating/popularity of the track is 10. I tried the below url but it does not satisfy the artist name. Can someone help me how to use this api?

http://api.gaana.com?type=song&subtype=most_popular&token=b2e6d7fbc136547a940516e9b77e5990&format=JSON&order=alltime&language=hindi

Comment: [search](http://developer.gaana.com/resources/meta-data-api/search/) by artist, then iterate through the results looking at rating.

Comment: Thanks.. i tried that like this http://api.gaana.com/?type=artist&subtype=subtype=artist_track_listing&token=b2e6d7fbc136547a940516e9b77e5990&format=JSON&order=alltime&language=hindi&rating=10&artist:name=kishor%20kumar but no result... I am not able to understand the documentation on how to write the query. can you have a look at it? http://developer.gaana.com/resources/meta-data-api/tracks/

Comment: I linked to the page that details the method you need to use. [Working query](http://api.gaana.com/?type=search&subtype=search_artist&key=kishor%20kumar&token=b2e6d7fbc136547a940516e9b77e5990&format=JSON)

Comment: It doesnt give the complete list. there are lots of kishor kumar songs in the database. The query give a small list

Answer (score 2):

In the Search API(Search Song) you can see,

> APIURL/?type=search&subtype=search_song&key=disco deewane

Just replace <strike>*disco deewane*</strike> with *kishore kumar*.

For example, http://api.gaana.com/?type=search&subtype=search_song&key=kishore%20kumar&token=b2e6d7fbc136547a940516e9b77e5990&format=JSON&order=alltime&language=hindi

There are 6486 tracks listed.

Comment: Yes! this is what I was looking for (i guess. need to look at it better) how did you find there are 6486 tracks? Is there a way to export this in a formatted way in excel?

Comment: The fields what I need is track_id, track_title, album_id, album_title, language, artwork, artist_id, name, popularity, rating, is_most_popular and remove unwanted stuff and export the formatted list. Can you help me with this?